# estado activo e inactivo en php

Tags: mysql, jquery, html5, ajax, html-tabla

Tengo un código, rescatado de [este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VEhSnDPONbA&ab_channel=CesarAugustoPerezTafur).

Seguí todos los pasos pero al momento de querer cambiar el estado con los botones de mi tabla, dando click, no pasa nada, ¿Alguien me podría ayudar a que funcione por favor?

Este es el archivo *usuario.php* en donde esta la tabla, solo copié la parte donde están los botones, por que considero que lo demás no es relevante.

```
<head>
<!--solo pondré los links relacionados al tema-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> <!---libreria jquery--->
        <script src="usuario.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
 <table>
 <?php if($datos['estado']!=1){
    echo'<td><button type="button"  id="btnActivar" class="btn btn-danger btnprueba btn-xs " 
    documento='.$datos["estado"].'  estado="1">Inactivo</button></td>';
}else{
  echo'<td><button type="button" id="btnActivar" class="btn btn-success btnprueba btn-xs " 
  documento='.$datos["estado"].' estado="0" >Activo</button></td>';
  if($datos['estado']!=1){ echo''; }else{ echo''; } if($datos['estado']!=1){ echo''; }else{ echo''; } 
}?>   
                  </table>
```

---

La tabla es así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Archivo usuario.js:

```
//alert("FUNCIONA");

$(".btnActivar").click(function(){
    
    var documento= $(this).attr("documento");
    var estado = $(this).attr("estado");
    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append("activarDocumento",documento);
    datos.append("activarUsuario",estado);

    $ajax({
        url:"usuario.ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: datos,
        cache:false,
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        success:function(respuesta){

        }
    })
    if(estado==0){
        $(this).removeClass('btn-success');
        $(this).addClass('btn_danger');
        $(this).html('Inactivo');
        $(this).attr('estado',1);
    }else{
        $(this).removeClass('btn-danger');
        $(this).addClass('btn_success');
        $(this).html('Activo');
        $(this).attr('estado',0);
    }
})
```

---

Archivo usuario.ajax.php:

```
<?php 

/*=============================================
 ACTIVAR USUARIO
 =============================================*/

  $activarUsuario;
  $activarDocumento;

  function ajaxActivarUsuario(){
  $tabla = "tblusuario";
  $item1 = "estado";
  $valor1 =$this -> activarUsuario;
  $item2 = "documento";
  $valor2 =$this -> activarDocumento;
  $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::mdlActualizarUsuario($tabla,$item1,$valor1,$item2,$valor2);

 }
 /*=============================================
ACTIVAR USUARIO
=============================================*/

if(isset($_POST['activarUsuario'])){
    $activarUsuario = new AjaxUsuarios();
    $activarUsuario -> activarUsuario=$_POST['activarUsuario'];
    $activarUsuario -> activarId=$_POST['activarId'];
    $activarUsuario ->ajaxActivarUsuario();
   }

?>
```

---

Archivo usuariomodelo.php:

```
<?php
 
    function mdlActualizarUsuario($tabla,$item1,$valor1,$item2,$valor2){
    $stmt = conexion::conexion()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET $item1 = :$item1 WHERE $item2 = :$item2");
    $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item1,$valor1,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item2,$valor2,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if($stmt->execute()){
     return "ok";
    }else{
     return "error";
    }
    $stmt ->close();
    $stmt = null;
 
   }
?>
```

Comment: Los botones no deberían tener algún `onClick` definido para reaccionar de alguna forma cuando les hagas click?

Comment: Olvidalo, ya lo vi, en usuario.js. Al hacer click entras en esa función?

Comment: Si se supone que asi debe funcionar hasta donde entiendo, probé el js con el alert comentado y si ridecciona , pero no funciona el codigo.

Comment: Bueno.... si fuera yo, para eliminar variables, comentaría la llamada a ajax, solo para ver qué está pasando con el cambio del estilo. Coloca unos console.log para que le puedas seguir el rastro a los eventos... o coloca breakpoints para saber si estás pasando por los sitios donde _suponemos_ que estás pasando.

Comment: Que escribo en el console log ? y donde va ?

Comment: Los console.log yo los voy colocando en el código para saber por donde voy.... por ejemplo, la primera linea del `$(".btnActivar").click(function(){`, yo pondría: `console.log("Hicieron click en un boton para activar/desactivar")`. Luego en los if/else colocaría otra línea para saber donde entré: `console.log("voy a activar")`, la otra diria desactivar... y así.

Comment: Gracias , el segundo console log, no se muestra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un problema con los selectores, intentas hacer una referencia a un botón que no existe, no es lo mismo `.btnActivar` que `#btnActivar` intentas acceder por clase, pero los botones no tienen esa clase, por eso no funciona. Ahora, te recomiendo que los listeners los bindees al DOM, hacerlo directamente al selector no siempre funciona. Primero, cambia tu HTML así

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btnprueba btn-xs btnActivar" 
  documento='.$datos["estado"].' estado="0" >Activo</button>
```

Quité el ID por que no lo usas, a menos que esté bindeado a otro listener. Ahora, por lo visto tu botón se arma en un ciclado, por lo que poner `id="btnActivar"` hará tu código inconsistente pues sólo debe haber un ID del mismo nombre en la vista.

Siempre que haya una reacción en la vista después de una llamada asíncrona, esa reacción va en la respuesta del callback, en este caso en el `success`del AJAX, si lo dejas como esta, el botón cambiará, independientemente si la acción en el backend fue satistactorio, de hecho el parámetro  `respuesta` en `success: function( respuesta )` debería indicarte si realmente se cambió o no.

Tu listener quedaría así, utiliza eficacia de constantes y reduce tu código

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnActivar', function () {
    const self = $(this);

    const documento = self.attr("documento");
    const estado = self.attr("estado");
    const datos = new FormData();
    datos.append("activarDocumento", documento);
    datos.append("activarUsuario", estado);

    $.ajax({
        url: "usuario.ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: datos,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (respuesta) {
            swapState(self, estado);
        }
    });
});

// Partí esta función fuera del código del botón, se ve más limpio
const swapState = (btn, estado) => {
    if ( Number( estado ) === 0) {
        btn.removeClass('btn-success');
        btn.addClass('btn-danger');
        btn.html('Inactivo');
        btn.attr('estado', 1);
        return;
    }

    btn.removeClass('btn-danger');
    btn.addClass('btn-success');
    btn.html('Activo');
    btn.attr('estado', 0);
};
```

Comment: Gracias !, pero me suelta este error                                                 
       usuario.js:45 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ajax is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (usuario.js:45)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.v.handle (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)

Comment: Ya lo corregí, le falta un `.` debió ser `$.ajax`

Comment: Gracias! lo probé, y si cambia el botón pero se queda sin color, intenté cambiar de inactivo a activo y si cambia, el botón activo ya no tiene color. Y sabes como puedo hacerlo para que también funcione al revez ?, de activo a inactivo ?

Comment: Te recomiendo repasar las clases de bootstrap, hay un error sintáctico en las clases. debería ser `btn-success` y `btn-danger` algunos que tu pusiste tiene `_` ya lo corregí, pruebalo, cambia sólo la función swapState()

Comment: Gracias ya tiene el color !,  yo cambié el botón inactivo, de la manera que tu hiciste el activo, pero ese no funciona, no cambia de activo a inactivo

Comment: Eso pasa por uqe utilicé equidad en lugar de igualdad, lo puedes ver en `estado === 0` eso implica que estado sea un 0 y sea numérico, Parsearemos el estado a un número, hice corrección, debería ser `if ( Number( estado ) === 0)`

Comment: Muchas gracias ! ya funciona,disculpa el atrevimiento pero, yo puedo actualizar el codigo de la pregunta para que me ayudes, a cambiarlo en la base de datos, porque hay no se cambia,  creo que es la parte del archivo ajax pero no se como configurarlo. Y por cierto, cuando recargo la pagina no se guardan los cambios,  seguramente es porque asi no esta en la base de datos cierto ?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114025/discussion-between-alberto-siurob-and-karol-yulieth-pacheco-rodrigue).